# How to use gcloud-node for storage transfer service

Tags: gcloud-node

I could not find any documentation on how to use gcloud-node for creating/listing a storage transfer job.

Any help on how I can achieve this using gcloud-node or node.js will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: can you please post your code anything what you tried so far ?

Comment: Nothing as I found no mention on Storage transfer service in here https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/storage/v1/ or here https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-node/#/docs/v0.27.0/storage